# Export pages png VBA

Tags: vba, parameters, export, png, visio

Seems to be pretty easy

```
Option Explicit




Sub ExportPagesAsPNG()

Dim currentPage As Visio.Page
    Dim currentDoc As Visio.Document
    Dim currentPath As String
    Dim currentPageName As String
  
    
    ' Pobranie bieżącego rysunku i jego ścieżki
    Set currentDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    currentPath = currentDoc.Path
    Debug.Print currentPath

     ' Debug.Print currentPath
    ' Dla każdej strony rysunku zapisz jako plik PNG
    For Each currentPage In currentDoc.Pages
        currentPageName = currentPage.Name
      '  Debug.Print currentPath & currentPageName & ".png"
        currentPage.Export currentPath & currentPageName & ".png"
    Next currentPage

End Sub
```

But can't find how to change resolution property, transparent color, sheetsize etc...
(parameters connected to exporting format).

currentPage.Export savePath & currentPage.Name & ".png", visExportPNG, currentPage.PageSheet.Section("PageSetup").Row("PageWidth").ResultIU, currentPage.PageSheet.Section("PageSetup").Row("PageHeight").ResultIU

Answer (score 0):

[Page.Export method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.selection.export) dont have these options!

You need use Application.Settings

```
    Application.Settings.SetRasterExportSize visRasterFitToSourceSize, 5#, 3#, visRasterInch
    Application.Settings.RasterExportDataFormat = visRasterInterlace
    Application.Settings.RasterExportColorFormat = visRaster24Bit
    Application.Settings.RasterExportRotation = visRasterNoRotation
    Application.Settings.RasterExportFlip = visRasterNoFlip
    Application.Settings.RasterExportBackgroundColor = 16777215
    Application.Settings.RasterExportTransparencyColor = 16777215
    Application.Settings.RasterExportUseTransparencyColor = True
```